# Concatenate columns to list of columns in Apache Spark DataFrame

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way in spark-sql to add a new column in a dataframe such that:

- the new column contains arrays of strings
- each string is the value of another column

Basically this is the same thing as the `concat` function except that the concatenation returns a list of strings instead of a big string seperated by an identifier

NB : I'm using the python API

Comment: just use the `array` function from dataframe API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the built-in `array` function. In scala this would look like:

```
df
.withColumn("col_arr",array(df.columns.map(c => col(c)):_*))
```